# UWP - How can I get strings resources from controls?

Tags: c#, string, xaml, localization, win-universal-app

I would like to add some languages in my app.

For example I would show with a xaml page:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="helloText" Text="Hello"/>
```

I saw that I can write on xaml.cs

```
helloText.Text=ResourceNamespace.ResxFileName.ResourceManager.GetString("Hello");
```

but isn't there a more direct solution?

Isn't there a way to add reference directly to Text attribute into the xaml page?

On MSDN I didn't find the answer, thanks.

Comment: Always start with [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/put-ui-strings-into-resources)

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the `x:Uid` of the text block to something, lets say `x:Uid=myTextBlock`.

in your Resources.resw file, add a entry `myTextBlock.Text` with value of the text you want to display.